# I want to know the bar graph code which shows y values relative probability not just count values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I typed the code in R:

```
ggplot(Traffic1,aes(Gender))+
geom_bar(aes(fill=Violation.Type))+
facet_wrap(~Violation.Type)
```

and I got the bar graph which y axis value is "count" not relative probability:

[image]

If I want to have y value relative probability for "each violation type", which code do I need to write?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Traffic1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Traffic1, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `stat_count`. I can't test it without you providing sample data, but this should work with your code:

```
ggplot(Traffic1,aes(x = Gender)) +
stat_count(mapping = aes(y=..prop.., fill=Violation.Type)) +
facet_wrap(~Violation.Type)
```

You might need to edit the `group` argument of stat_count if the values in each facet are not grouped correctly.